# Testing endpoint under auth with Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm struggling to write tests for an endpoint that is under auth (token). In particular, when writing my test, I'm not able to chain the login request with my second request, despite providing the token received as part of the login request.

*LoginEndpoint.kt*

```
const val LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "$API_VERSION/login"

@Location(LOGIN_ENDPOINT)
class Login

fun Route.loginEndpoint(patientsRepository: Repository<Patient>, authProvider: AuthProvider) {
    post<Login> {
        val params = call.receive<Parameters>()
        val userId = params["id"] ?: return@post call.respond(status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message = "Missing user id")

        val user = patientsRepository.get(userId)
        if (user != null) {
            val token = authProvider.generateToken(user.id!!)
            call.respond(TextContent("{ \"token\": \"$token\" }", ContentType.Application.Json))
        } else {
            call.respond(status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message = "User with id $userId does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

*LoginEndpointTest.kt* (passing, all good)

```
    @Test
    fun `given user exists then returns 200 and token`() {
        val userId = "paco123"
        val token = "magic_token_123"
        withTestApplication({
            givenTestModule()
        }) {
            every { authProvider.generateToken(userId) } answers { token }
            givenPatientExists(userId)
            with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/$API_VERSION/login") {
                addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                setBody("id=$userId")
            }) {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
                assertEquals("{ \"token\": \"magic_token_123\" }", response.content)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun Application.givenTestModule() {
        module(
            testing = true,
            repositoryModule = TestingRepositoryModule,
            authProvider = authProvider
        )
    }
```

Now, the problematic endpoint.

*ProfileEndpoint.kt*

```
const val PATIENTS_API_ENDPOINT = "$API_VERSION/profile"

@Location(PATIENTS_API_ENDPOINT)
class ProfileEndpoint

fun Route.profileEndpoint(patientsRepository: Repository<Patient>) {
    authenticate("jwt") {
        get<ProfileEndpoint> {
            val apiUser: Patient = call.apiUser!!
            val id = apiUser.id!!
            val patient = patientsRepository.get(id)
            when (patient != null) {
                false -> call.respond(status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message = "Patient with id $id does not exist")
                true -> call.respond(status = HttpStatusCode.OK, message = patient.map())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my failing test

*ProfileEndpointTest.kt*

```
    @Test
    fun `given user is logged in then returns 200 and profile`() {
        val userId = "paco123"
        val token = "magic_token_123"
        withTestApplication({
            givenTestModule()
        }) {
            every { authProvider.generateToken(userId) } answers { token }
            givenPatientExists(userId)

            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/$API_VERSION/login") {
                addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                setBody("id=$userId")
            }

            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/$API_VERSION/profile") {
                addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            }.apply {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is:

```
expected:<200 OK> but was:<401 Unauthorized>
Expected :200 OK
Actual   :401 Unauthorized
```

*AuthProvider.kt*

```
open class AuthProvider(secret: String = System.getenv(Environment.JWT_SECRET)) {
    private val algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512(secret)

    fun getVerifier(): JWTVerifier = JWT
        .require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer(APP_NAME)
        .build()

    fun generateToken(userId: String): String = JWT.create()
        .withSubject(SUBJECT)
        .withIssuer(APP_NAME)
        .withClaim(CLAIM, userId)
        .withExpiresAt(expiresAt())
        .sign(algorithm)

    private fun expiresAt() = Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + MILLIES_PER_DAY * TOKEN_DAYS_LENGTH)
}

val ApplicationCall.apiUser get() = authentication.principal<Patient>()
```

I've tried using `cookiesSession` like in this documentation's example https://ktor.io/servers/testing.html#preserving-cookies but it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can see you mocking your auth to provide the token when you login, but I do not see where you do any mocking to handle the token itself when it is used.